# How to link action UISlider to UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have two view's `UISlider` and `UIScrollView` added to `UIView`  I am displaying images in grid formate on `UIScrollView` like 2*10 matrix.  and i have customized my UISlider and added to UIView. Now when i am changing UISlider value the scrollview automatically pushes.  Can any on advice me for this implementation.

@thanks in advance

Regards
A Kiran Kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `NSNotification`. Add a notification observer to scrollView first, when changed the UISlider, post a notification to make the scrollView scrolls automatically.